# Android: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build an existing project in Android Studio on a MAC and I'm running into this build error:

```
Could not determine artifacts for io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0-RC1
          > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/io/reactivex/rxjava2/rxandroid/2.0.0-RC1/rxandroid-2.0.0-RC1.aar'.
             > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/io/reactivex/rxjava2/rxandroid/2.0.0-RC1/rxandroid-2.0.0-RC1.aar'.
                > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:80 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Operation timed out
```

_
_
_

Seems to me Android Studio cannot access jcenter.bintray.com:80...so here is what I tried so far:

1. I can access jcenter.bintray.com:80 from my browser with no issue.
2. I can download the file at: http://jcenter.bintray.com/io/reactivex/rxjava2/rxandroid/2.0.0-RC1/rxandroid-2.0.0-RC1.aar. --- from my browser with NO issue
3. I configured my Android Studio to look for auto proxy settings
   (Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > http proxy > I selected
   "auto-detect proxy settings" and in the resulting box input my
   network user name and password)
4. I also tried creating a gradle.properties file including (populated with values of course):

   systemProp.http.proxyPort=
   systemProp.http.proxyUser=
   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
        systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
        systemProp.https.proxyHost=
        systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=
        systemProp.http.proxyHost=
        systemProp.https.proxyPort=
   systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=
   systemProp.https.proxyUser=

Is there something I missed / or what else could be the issue?

Comment: Do you use `gradle` ?

Comment: @LiJianixm   Yes, you'll see I also tried adding a gradle.properties file as well.

Comment: Does `RxAndroid 2.0.1` works fine?

Comment: I added the correct parameters in System Settings > http proxy > Manual Proxy Settings and then it worked